# How to print a string with HTML tags as HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a small project where I grab JSON data from a url and parse it. All that is fine, the issue comes when I try to print the results to my HTML page. I have the data I need, and it comes with included HTML tags, so I'd just like to stick it on my page and be on my day. Every attempt below shows the result as

`<ul> <li>Place this item in the&nbsp;<strong>Blue Bin</strong>.</li> </ul>`

on my HTML page. It should be an unordered list with list items. I shouldn't be seeing the tags.

I've tried:

`var htmlString = $.parseHTML(data[1].body);
$content.append( htmlString );`

and:

`var htmlString = JSON.stringify(data[1].body);
$("#ObjectId").html("<pre>" + htmlString + "</pre>");`

I don't know what else to try. What am I missing?

btw- data[1].body is the JSON data, it contains the first line of code above.

Comment: Try logging out `htmlString` in the first example; see if it actually parses correctly.

Comment: what do you mean by logging out?

Comment: like `console.log(htmlString)`

Comment: `console.log()`

Comment: yes, htmlString parses correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```js
let temp =`<ul> <li>Place this item in the&nbsp;<strong>Blue Bin</strong>.</li> </ul>`

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= temp
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add an id to the HTML element, and then add it as innerHTML to that element with `document.getElementById(my-id).innerHTML = '<p>your string</p>`

[more info!](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Answer (score 1):

This will get your job done.

```
<p>Hello World</p>

$('p').html('<b>Hi</b>');
```